# GPUImage: is there callback function when a filter is done processing a frame from GPUImageVideoCamera

Tags: ios, iphone, callback, camera, gpuimage

Basically, I want to grab frames from iPhone camera, input them to a custom filter and get the result from that custom filter into my own CPU memory for further processing. The question is given that camera sends 30 frames to the filter per second, How do I know when a frame is done by that filter? In other words, is there a callback function when the filter is finished processing each frame from the camera? the code is as following:

```
    videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    MyOwnGPUFilter *mof=[[MyOwnGPUFilter alloc] init];
    [videoCamera addTarget:mof];
    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, I recommend using a GPUImageRawDataOutput class and setting its `newFrameAvailableBlock`. If you make the GPUImageRawDataOutput the target of your filter, that block will be triggered the instant the filter finishes processing.

The GPUImageRawDataOutput gives you direct access to the raw color data, and uses the most efficient means it can to pull that down. That should make it easy to pass those color bytes into your CPU-side processing.

Comment: Thank you Brad. I can't believe you reply so quickly. GPUImage is a great tool. I will try your suggestion later. by the way, I found frameProcessingCompletionBlock in class GPUImageOutput. Is it also something gets called when a filter is finished?

Comment: @user3348157 - Yes, but I do hook into that in a couple of the more complex image processing operations (I think the corner and line detectors use it, but they have their own callbacks), so if it fails in certain cases that's why. Should work for most filters, but if you're reading to the CPU anyway, I highly recommend the raw data output. On devices that support it, I use texture caches to speed up the reads significantly.

Comment: Do I still need to call prepareForImageCapture of MyOwnGPUFilter or GPUImageRawDataOutput in order to get faster download from GPU?

Comment: @user3348157 - The GPUImageRawDataOutput handles all this properly by default. If you wish to use a standard filter and capture an image from that, -prepareForImageCapture will trigger the use of texture caches over `glReadPixels()` on the next image capture operation.